# How to return argc in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu, argc

I'm trying to return *argc* in assembly but the program returns 0. I'm using GNU 2.28 on Windows 10 !

There is my code:

```
.section .text

.globl main
main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp

    movl 8(%ebp), %eax

    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp
    ret

.globl _start
_start:
    pushl 0(%esp)
    call main
    addl 4, %esp
    
    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

I'm using the following commands to generate my exe:

> ```
> as --32 test.s -o test.obj
> ld -m i386pe test -o test.exe
> ```

Comment: `int $0x80` is linux system call. You do not want that on windows.

Answer (score 2):

MS Windows doesn't provide pointers to separated arguments pushed on machine stack, as GNU Linux does. When an executable program is launched from the terminal window with command e.g.

```
 as --32 test.s -o test.obj
```

you need to retrieve the command line using API function from "kernel32.dll" and parse it yourself.

Invokation of API function [GetCommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) returns pointer to a string which contains the entire command, starting with the executable name (`as` in this example), and ending with NUL character. When the program is launched from Explorer, the executable name may be completed to form the full path to executable, for instance `"C:\Program Files\GNU utilities\as.exe"`.
Now you should parse the string character by character, test each one if it's argument-separator (white space), taking into account if you're inside double quotes, and count argument numbers.

You can find examples in my macrolibraries for Windows at [GetArgCount](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/winapi.htm#GetArgCount) or for Linux at [GetArgCount](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/linabi.htm#GetArgCount).